# Replacing background image for higher quality one if user is on retina device

Tags: javascript, html, css, retina-display

I'm attempting to make my first retina ready website, but I came across the problem when I need to replace images to higher resolution in css. I'm not sure how to, for example, have standard image as a background and then if user is on retina machine have same image but at higher res (at the moment I have both low res and high res images).
Can anyone suggest good sources or explain how to do this? Preferably a css and cross-browser solution, but it could also be javascript or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the css media query

```
   device-pixel-ratio,
   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio,
   -o-min-device-pixel-ratio,
   -Webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio {
     …
   }
```

Comment: Hi, I think I've seen this before somewhere, but I can't find it again. do you have a good source that explains this in more depth please?

Comment: Here I found this, will this work for all browsers or webkit only?? @media all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
  #logo {
    background-image: url('/images/my_image@2x.png');
    background-size: 200px 100px;
  }
}

Comment: The `-webkit` prefix means exactly that:  webkit.  The answer already provides the necessary media query properties for the other browsers that support it (though the syntax is incomplete).  However, Opera expects you to use a fraction (3/2) instead of a decimal (1.5).

Answer (score 0):

What seems like the easiest solution to me is to take advantage of css. You have a base class that sets up the picture for the background like you said, but you have another class over ride the background image to a higher resolution.

Using this as a source you can do this to detect if it's a retina display and add a class to the element.

http://briancray.com/posts/detect-retina-displays-with-javascript

```
var retina = window.devicePixelRatio > 1;
if (retina) {
    // the user has a retina display
    //add code to add the class to your element.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the device on the server-side also could be a solution. Projects such as WURFL and Tera-WURFL let you to know the device before making response, so you can send right css file.